# Python: Counting unique instances of lists/DataFrame in a list of lists/DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a for loop that creates - let's say - 1000 lists. The generation of these lists are slightly randomized, so there is a difference between the generated lists, but there will also be some that overlap. And I want to count how many times a unique list occurs, that is, how many times a given list overlaps with another generated list.

Each item in the list is formatted as follows:

`TeamRecord(name='GER', group='F', p=9, gs=6, ga=2, defeated=['SWE', 'MEX', 'KOR']),`

If it helps, here's the context: As the list item might indicate, I'm simulating the soccer World Cup group stages and each simulation results in a list containing each teams' performance for that given simulation. So I want to see, given for example 10000 simulations, which outcomes are most likely given how many times they occur in the simulation.

I think this is more of an abstract question, and I don't really have any code to provide that would be useful. I did try to tinker a bit with converting the lists to DataFrames and thought of using the .equals method, but I'm not sure how that could be done effectively.

So again, the question is:

How would you go about counting the occurence of each unique instance of a list generated by a for-loop - that is, all the items in the list should be identicel with another generated list. Is this even possible to do, or is it simply a dumb way of looking at it?

**EDIT**
Simple example illustrating the purpose:

```
list_of_lists = [['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'],
                ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'],
                ['Test4', 'Test5', 'Test6']]
```

How would you go about counting that there are two instances of the first two lists, 1 of the third list and so on.

Comment: Start with a [mcve], and then we can tell you whether it's possible or not.

Comment: @coldspeed like so?

Comment: Yes, and the expected output is? How do DataFrames factor into this?

Comment: @coldspeed ah, I'll do another edit. Thanks!

Comment: The best answer is **very** specific to the type of object you are counting. If you have a tuple or frozenset (or a list / set which can be converted to one of these) you can use hashing. Please specify *exactly* the nature of the objects you are counting.

Comment: I think if the question makes bad prose (nuanced, ambigious, reprtitive), if makes bad code. with your final edit it looks you might want to hash list entries to something indexable, then count

Answer (score 1):

Any solution will be specific to the type of object you are counting. I deal **only** with the specific example you have highlighted, i.e. a list of lists of strings.

You can use `collections.Counter` on tuple versions of your sublists. This works because tuples are hashable while lists are not.

```
from collections import Counter

L = [['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'],
     ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'],
     ['Test4', 'Test5', 'Test6']]

res = Counter(map(tuple, L))

print(res)

Counter({('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'): 2,
         ('Test4', 'Test5', 'Test6'): 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple diagnostics of multiple entries:

```
from collections import Counter

lists = [['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'],
         ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'],
         ['Test4', 'Test5', 'Test6']]

def hasher(x):
    return ''.join(x)

hashed = [hasher(x) for x in lists]
cnt = Counter(hashed)
print(cnt)

# you can reverse to to original list 
# if you world to combine it with the count, in some fashion
lists2 = [(cnt[hasher(x)], x) for x in lists]
```

Comment: No, this is a bad idea. Here `['abc', 'def']` will be equivalent to `['abcd', 'ef']`, when in fact they are different.

Comment: fancy for another hasher function, @jpp?

Comment: Sure, see my solution :)

Comment: `map(tuple, L)` is great chioce! )